# Can't find description of MaterialApp routes parameters

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

Currently I'm learning dart & flutter. During reading flutter cookbook I found construction like this ([source](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes#2-define-the-routes)):

```
'/': (context) => FirstScreen()
```

After this foundation, I tried to find something that explains that in dart documentation, but didn't found something useful.

I even don't how is this thing is calling.

---

Please, tell me what this line is doing (except that it's redirecting to Widget after fat arrow) or, what is it calling, to continue research.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: its a `Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext)>`, when you call `Navigator.pushNamed`, the name is looked up in this map, and the corresponding function is called to build the widget.

### Longer answer

You may find it helpful to use your IDE's "go-to definition" function (in most IDEs this is ctrl/cmd + click), which will take you to a location in source where a particular thing is defined.

Firstly, this is inside something called a "map literal". A map literal looks a bit like this:

```dart
final map = {
  'hello': 'world'
};
```

This is equivalent to writing:

```dart
final map = Map();
map['hello'] = 'world';
```

It's just a shorthand to create a pre-filled `Map`. So the following is a `Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext)`.

```dart
routes: {
  '/': (context) => MyWidget(),
  '/other': (context) => OtherWidget(),
}
```

This allows you to look up a value by its 'key', and the value you get back is a `Widget Function(BuildContext)`:

```dart
BuildContext context = ...;  // get a context from somewhere
Widget Function(BuildContext) function = routes['/'];  // look up the key '/'
Widget widget = function(context);  // call the function with the context
```

You're describing the `routes` parameter of the `MaterialApp()` constructor. If you ctrl+click on the word `routes`, it takes you to the following definition:

```dart
  /// The application's top-level routing table.
  ///
  /// When a named route is pushed with [Navigator.pushNamed], the route name is
  /// looked up in this map. If the name is present, the associated
  /// [WidgetBuilder] is used to construct a [MaterialPageRoute] that performs
  /// an appropriate transition, including [Hero] animations, to the new route.
  ///
  /// {@macro flutter.widgets.widgetsApp.routes}
  final Map<String, WidgetBuilder>? routes
```

Essentially, this is a way to tell Flutter what you mean by each name. If you called `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home')`, and you didn't have this map, Flutter would have no idea that `/home` was meant to take the user to `HomeWidget()` (or whatever it's called). This map is a way of providing the link between names and widgets.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't give +1 rep, because it says me "You need at least 15 reputation...", I'm sorry :(